# Get the difference between top and last value in result set

Tags: sql-server

My table looks something like

```
deal_id   test_value    run_date
820117648   1.2     2014-03-31
820117648   1.33    2014-04-30
820117648   1.33    2014-05-30
820117648   1.26    2014-06-30
820117648   1.11    2014-07-31
820117648   0.58    2014-09-30
820117648   1.64    2014-10-31
820117648   0.64    2014-11-28
820117648   3.65    2014-12-31
820117648   3.8     2015-03-11

820117649   0.64    2014-09-31
820117649   0.23    2014-10-31
820117649   0.64    2014-11-28
820117649   3.65    2014-12-31
820117649   3.8     2015-03-11


SELECT deal_id,test_value,run_date  FROM  ems.cdotests
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -4 Getdate())
```

I am trying to grab the last  4 run_date record from the whole set and then 
I need to find the difference between the testValue on the first rundate of my select criteria and the last rundate i.e for deal_id 820117649    3.8 - 0.23 = 3.57 and for deal_id 820117648 it should be 3.8 -1.64 = 2.16
This is the large table with multiple deal id and several run_date associated with each dealid and may have data for the last 15 years or so
Any suggestion would be really helpfull

Comment: Which version of MSSQL? `Select @@Version`

Comment: max and min will give me a deviation of 3.8-0.5 = 3.3 which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. It will not be bound to particular `deal_id`.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, V MONEY, D DATE )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '20140101' ),
        ( 1, 4, '20140102' ),
        ( 1, 2, '20140103' ),
        ( 1, 7, '20140104' ),
        ( 2, 5, '20140104' ),
        ( 2, 8, '20140110' ),
        ( 2, 11, '20140105' );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        MIN(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Min ,
                        MAX(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Max
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c1.ID ,
            c2.V - c1.V AS V
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID AND c1.D < c2.D
    WHERE   ( c1.D = c1.MIN OR c1.D = c1.MAX ) AND ( c2.D = c2.MIN OR c2.D = c2.MAX )
```

Output:

```
ID  V
1   6.00
2   3.00
```

You have changed you question. For latest 6 month, add filter CTE above main CTE:

```
;WITH    filter
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D DESC ) AS RN
               FROM     @t
             ),
        cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        MIN(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Min ,
                        MAX(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Max
               FROM     filter
               WHERE    RN <= 6
             )
    SELECT  c1.ID ,
            c2.V - c1.V AS V
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID AND c1.D < c2.D
    WHERE   ( c1.D = c1.MIN OR c1.D = c1.MAX ) 
            AND ( c2.D = c2.MIN OR c2.D = c2.MAX ) 
            AND (c2.V - c1.V > 5)
```

Comment: if i want to add one more criteria saying that i want to select only the id's which has deviation greater than 5 ,so where should i add that coindition

Comment: @user3290807, see edited query. I've added  `AND (c2.V - c1.V > 5)` to the very end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deal_Id ORDER BY deal_Id) Rn
           ,deal_Id
           ,test_value
           ,run_date
    FROM ems.cdotests
)
SELECT id1 deal_id, t2 - t1 diff
FROM (SELECT c1.deal_id id1
             ,c1.test_value t1
             ,c2.deal_id id2
             , c2.test_value t2
      FROM C c1 
      INNER JOIN C c2 ON c1.deal_id = c2.deal_id
      WHERE c1.Rn = 1
      AND c2.Rn = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(Rn) FROM C GROUP BY deal_id)
     ) t
```

Comment: it says Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: HOW DO I fetch THE LAST N Month of records in this

Comment: You can put any kind of where clauses in your main query (the query inside WITH). By using a CTE, you can run a query and then based on the result set you can make other queries on top of that.

Comment: Whis is  c1.Rn = 1 in the query

Comment: Means the first ranking row

Answer (score 0):

So late to answer, but a way is this:

```
;with t as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by deal_id order by run_date desc) seq
    from ems.cdotests 
)
select 
    t1.deal_id, t1.run_date run_date1, t1.test_value test_value1, 
                t2.run_date run_date4, t2.test_value test_value4, 
    t1.test_value - t2.test_value diff
from t t1
join t t2
  on t1.deal_id = t2.deal_id
where t1.seq = 1
  and t2.seq = 4
  -- as an extra condition of those should have at least 5 records:
  and exists (select 1 from t ti where ti.deal_id = t1.deal_id and ti.seq > 5)
```

[**`[SQL Fiddle]`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2892/1)